# 16-point DFT of a real signal x[n]

Tags: dft

The 16-point DFT of a real signal x[n] in the domain 0 ≤ k ≤ 8 is given by
$$X[k] = 1 + (1 − 3j)\delta[k − 2] + (5 + 2j)\delta[k − 4] + (3 − 7j)\delta[k − 6] + \delta[k − 8]$$.
(a) Determine $X[k]$ for $9 \le k \le 15$.
(b) Determine the related signal $x[n]$.

Comment: Welcome, again!  Your question reads like either a homework question or a self-study question. While these sorts of questions are on-topic here, in order to be answerable we need to see where your understanding of how to solve the problem breaks down so we can help you understand how to approach the problem. This is not a forum for having your homework done for free on.

Comment: sir i have tried it but i am unable to get the related signal x[n] which is part b i need help in that part